# split XML node by half (XSLT transformation)

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Could you please help how to split in half node with subnodes.

Input:

```
<RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
 <FileHashRule Id="1">
  <Conditions>
   <FileHashCondition>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xCC864"></FileHash>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x9D973"></FileHash>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xA92EF"></FileHash>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x279CD"></FileHash>
   </FileHashCondition>
  </Conditions>
 </FileHashRule>
</RuleCollection>
```

Output:

```
<RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
 <FileHashRule Id="hard-coded guid1">
  <Conditions>
   <FileHashCondition>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xCC864"></FileHash>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x9D973"></FileHash>
   </FileHashCondition>
  </Conditions>
 </FileHashRule>
 <FileHashRule Id="hard-coded guid2">
  <Conditions>
   <FileHashCondition>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xA92EF"></FileHash>
    <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x279CD"></FileHash>
   </FileHashCondition>
  </Conditions>
 </FileHashRule>
</RuleCollection>
```

Unfortunatly I dont have expirience with xslt and did not find such an examples how to do it.

**Updated**
I tried one of the suggested approach below and have this https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNq/3 nodes doesn't copy

xslt:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:variable name="fileHash" select="/FileHashRule/Conditions/FileHashCondition/FileHash" />
        <xsl:variable name="half" select="count($fileHash) div 2" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
        <RuleCollection>
            <FileHashRule>
                <xsl:attribute name="Id">ad22d301-eb88-485d-ae1d-537790bdebfa</xsl:attribute>
                    <Conditions>

                        <FileHashCondition>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$fileHash[position() &lt;= $half]" />

                        </FileHashCondition>
                    </Conditions>
            </FileHashRule>

                <FileHashRule>
                <xsl:attribute name="Id">ad22d301-eb88-485d-ae1d-537790bdebfb</xsl:attribute>
                    <Conditions>

                        <FileHashCondition>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$fileHash[position() &gt; $half]" />
                        </FileHashCondition>
                    </Conditions>
            </FileHashRule>


        </RuleCollection>
        </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RuleCollection>
       <FileHashRule Id="ad22d301-eb88-485d-ae1d-537790bdebfa">
          <Conditions>
             <FileHashCondition/>
          </Conditions>
       </FileHashRule>
       <FileHashRule Id="ad22d301-eb88-485d-ae1d-537790bdebfb">
          <Conditions>
             <FileHashCondition/>
          </Conditions>
       </FileHashRule>
    </RuleCollection>
```

Comment: Define "half", esp. in the case of odd number of nodes. -- Note also that the output you show is not well-formed XML (lacks a single root element).

Comment: @michael.hor257k, corrected, about half, doesnt matter

Comment: When you're learning a new language, you don't need experience and you don't need an example that solves the exact problem you're tackling, you need a good book or tutorial that teaches the concepts, and you should learn by doing simple exercises first before you try and tackle a more difficult problem.

Comment: You keep changing your input XML format. Now that you have added the `RuleCollection` wrapper, you must change the `fileHash` variable definition to: `<xsl:variable name="fileHash" select="/RuleCollection/FileHashRule/Conditions/FileHashCondition/FileHash" />` - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNq/4

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thanks a lot, works great. what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the half point quite simply by:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileHash" select="/RuleCollection/FileHashRule/Conditions/FileHashCondition/FileHash" />
<xsl:variable name="half" select="count($fileHash) div 2" />
```

Then just create the two `FileHashRule` elements and use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$fileHash[position() &lt;= $half]" />
```

to populate the first one, and:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$fileHash[position() &gt; $half]" />
```

for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from something like ([XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNq)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="//xs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='x[position() &lt;= last() div 2]'/>
    </xsl:copy>

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='x[position() &gt; last() div 2]'/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will split

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <xs a="b">
        <will-not-be-copied/>
        <x>1</x>
        <x>2</x>
        <x>3</x>
        <x>4</x>
    </xs>
</data>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <xs a="b">
      <x>1</x>
      <x>2</x>
   </xs>
   <xs a="b">
      <x>3</x>
      <x>4</x>
   </xs>
</data>
```

Note though, that you need to clarify how you want to deal with tags like `<will-not-be-copied>` and you might want to add your `id` values to the splitted `<xs>` tags.

Comment: Your wrappers are identical - unlike the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FileHashRule">
  <FileHashRule Id="{@Id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="one"/>
  </FileHashRule>
  <FileHashRule Id="{@Id + 1}">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="two"/>
  </FileHashRule>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FileHash[position() > last() div 2]" mode="one"/>
<xsl:template match="FileHash[position() &lt;= last() div 2]" mode="two"/>
```

The first rule says: by default, copy nodes unchanged.

The second rule says: For a FileHashRule, create two copies, incrementing the @Id attribute in the second.

The third rule says: during the first phase, skip any FileHash element in the second half of the list.

The fourth rule says: during the second phase, skip any FileHash element in the first half of the list.